# Segmentation fault on array of strings

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to create a function that prints out a sequence of letters in the alphabet in order given a parameter count. For example, if the count was four the output would be strings `"a" "ab" "abc" "abcd"`. However, if the count was more than 26 it would loop around back to 'a', so the output for count 28 would be `"a"....."abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"`. Below is the code I have written. When I try to run this code however I get a segmentation fault error on the line with

```
out[i][j] = let
```

and I am having some difficulty figuring out why.

```
char **sequences(int count) {

    int letter = 0;
    char **out = (char**)calloc(10, sizeof(char*));
    char **array = NULL;

    int size = 0;
    int cap = 10;
    char let;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                
        if (size == cap) {
            cap *= 2;
            array = (char **)realloc(out, cap*sizeof(char *));
            if (array != NULL) {
                out = array;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
                
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        
            if (letter < 26) {
                let = 97 + letter;
                printf("%c\n", let);
                out[i][j] = let;
                printf("%c\n", out[i][j]);
                letter++;
                size++;
            } else {
                letter = 0;
                let = 97 + letter;
                printf("%c\n", let);
                out[i][j] = let;
                printf("%c\n", out[i][j]);
                letter++;
                size++;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}

int main(void) {
   
    char** first;
    char** second;    

    first = sequences(1);
    printf("sequences[0] should be \"a\", got: %s\n", sequences[0]);

    second = sequences(28);
    printf("sequences[27] should be \"ab...yzab\", got: %s\n", sequences[27]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're never allocating memory for `out[i]`.

Comment: Please put your main() routine where you call the function.  More detail you can provide the better.

Comment: There's no need to keep reallocating `out`. Just allocate `count` elements the first time.

Comment: You're also not modifying `size` at any point.

Comment: @jarmod my mistake I forgot to add the increments, they're in there now

Comment: @netskink just added it, sorry about that

Comment: late to the answer, but here's a [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/b7569qh8b)

Comment: very good.  The main will help folks understand better.  No need to apologize to me, pal.  I appreciate your politeness.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you're never allocating any memory for `out[i]`. You can do this with `calloc(i+1, sizeof(char))`. I add 1 for the null terminator.

There's no need to keep growing `out` with `realloc()`. You know that the final size will be `count`, so just allocate that much at the beginning.

You don't need a separate `letter` counter. You can use modular arithmetic to wrap around at 26.

```
char **sequences(int count) {
    char **out = malloc(count * sizeof(char*));
    if (out == NULL) {
        abort();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        out[i-1] = calloc(i+1, sizeof(char));
        if (out[i-1] == NULL) {
            abort();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            char let = 'a' + (j % 26);
            out[i][j] = let;
            printf("%c\n", let);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed `i` to start at `1` because we don't want an empty string, but forgot to adjust for this in the array index.

Comment: actually making it `out[i-1]` causes a segmentation fault

Comment: Why does that cause a segmentation fault? `i-1` should always be in range, since the loop starts at `i = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very easy. You allocate an array of pointers, but you do not allocate any space for the strings. As you use `calloc` all pointers are NULL.

In this line (and in all others where you use `out[i][j]`)

```
out[i][j] = let;
```

you dereference NULL pointer. It is **U**ndefined **B**ehaviour (UB) and in your case it is expressing itself as SegFault.

Comment: Technically the array elements are zero bytes. That's not necessarily a null pointer.

Comment: @Barmar I try to make it simple fo OP - standard defines NULL as (void *)0 or simple zero, then all pointers are NULL.

Comment: I know what the standard says. That's a null pointer constant, it doesn't mean that the internal representation is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the assignment is, but you can forgo the allocations entirely, simply jump straight to the output, which is a bit simpler IMO if that's all you need:

```c
void printSequences(size_t count)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            putchar('a' + (j % 26));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yzev5e9K9)